# Android service not running in separate process

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service declared in my AndroidManifest.xml to run in a separate process than the rest  of my app via the `android:process` attribute of my service. However when I view the app via Settings > Apps > Running, it only shows that I have one process and one service. Should I not have two processes?

Here is my service declaration in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application ...
   android:process=":MyAppProcess">
   ...
   <service
       android:name="com.example.MyService"
       android:label="My Service"
       android:exported="false"
       android:process=":MyServiceProcess"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check my this code

```
<service android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
     android:exported=["true" | "false"]
     android:icon="drawable resource"
     android:isolatedProcess=["true" | "false"]
     android:label="string resource"
     android:name="string"
     android:permission="string"
     android:process="string" >
. . .
</service>
```

please set  `android:isolatedProcess=true`

read [Developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#isolated)

Comment: Can you post your service class you are using. Extending service class doesn't mean it will automatically opens another thread to do its task.

Comment: You shouldn't have to set isolatedProcess just to get it to run in a separate process. That is what the process attribute is for, right? Otherwise I don't see anything in your code that would affect the process.